# Can't get Messagebox to display List

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to have a `MessageBox` appear that shows the changelog inside my C# program

This is the text file.

> Current Version 0.2.3.4
>
> Added Hash decoder
>
> Attempted to change code into OOP design
>
> Cleaned up random code with ReSharper
>
> Version 0.1.3.4 - 8/29/2016
>
> No change logs before this point

The goal is to get the text between `Current Version 0.2.3.4` and `Version 0.1.3.4 - 8/29/2016`

I've had tried doing this with the code below

```
Regex changeLogMatch = new Regex("Current Version\\s.*?\\n(.*?\\n)+Version\\s.*?\\s\\-\\s\\d");
Match changeLogInfo = changeLogMatch.Match(changeLog);
int changeLogCount = Regex.Matches(changeLog, "Current Version\\s.*?\\n(.*?\\n)+Version\\s.*?\\s\\-\\s\\d").Count;
List<string> changeLogList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < changeLogCount; i++)
{
    changeLogList.Add(changeLogInfo.Groups[1].Captures[i].ToString());
}
string changeLogString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, changeLogList);
Console.WriteLine(changeLogString);
MessageBox.Show("New Changes" + Environment.NewLine + changeLogString
                , "New Version Found: " + newVersion);
```

The issue I'm having is that `changeLogString` only displays `Added Hash decoder` and nothing else.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `changeLogCount` always be 1. So in `changeLogList` will be always `changeLogInfo.Groups[1].Captures[0].ToString()` what is refers to `Added Hash decoder` string.

You are checking for `"Current Version\\s.*?\\n((.*?\\n)+)Version\\s.*?\\s\\-\\s\\d"` regex, it is matching the whole string and matches 1 time. But the first group `(.*?\\n)` matches 3 times. So, if you are checking for count of matches of full regex - you will get 1, if you want to get number of captures of first group - you will get 3.

So you should fix your code in the following manner:

```
Regex changeLogMatch = new Regex("Current Version\\s.*?\\n(.*?\\n)+Version\\s.*?\\s\\-\\s\\d");
Match changeLogInfo = changeLogMatch.Match(changeLog);

string changeLogString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, changeLogInfo.Groups[1].Captures.OfType<Capture>());
Console.WriteLine(changeLogString);
```

Note, that you have no need to iterate through captures - the required string will be stored in `changeLogString`.